# Angular2: insert component element next to host element

Tags: angular, inject, siblings

Is it possible with Angular2 to let the component element insert NEXT to it's host element? The DynamicComponentLoader can do that, i know. But i want to tell Angular2 to do that in my component class or from the compiled template.

**Why do i need that?**
I have built a recursive table component which loads from a tree data structure.
The problem with recursion here is that Angular2 cannot replace my host element and the HTML table does not ignore unknown nested tags. The result is that the entire table layout breaks.

Here is the produced markup:

```
<table>
 <tbody class="my-component"> <!-- this works fine so far -->
  <tr>
   <td>Level 1</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- first level descent -->
  <my-component> <!-- Here is the problem. Breaks the table -->
   <tr>
    <td>Level 2</td>
   </tr>
   <!-- next level descent -->
   <my-component> <!-- i dont't want it to nest. Should add as sibling of host -->
    <tr>
     <td>Level 3</td>
    </tr>
   </my-component>
  </my-component>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is what it should look like:

```
<table>
 <tbody class="my-component">
  <tr>
   <td>Level 1</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- first level descent -->
  <my-component></my-component> <!-- No nesting. Won't break the table -->
  <tr>
   <td>Level 2</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- next level descent -->
  <my-component></my-component>
  <tr>
   <td>Level 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope you guys get my problem. If not, i will invest some time and create a plunker.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/5UxKYk7DupuHE9jnTaiv?p=preview) is a plunker example

Comment: How would Angular ever stop inserting `my-components`? You don't have an exit condition if you aren't using DCL.

Comment: @Harangue I added a Plunker example

Comment: I think the plunker example doesn't work? can you reproduce it in stackblitz?